# Singlestore (MemSQL)

Tags: sql, singlestore

I have a Singlestore (previously MemSQL) cloud database set up.

My software is running in the background, constantly writing to a table.

When I try to query this table, it takes 10+ seconds. When the software is shut off, the query takes milliseconds.

What would be the reason for this? And is there anything that can be done to mitigate against this?

Comment: add error handling and output the error, further mysql usually log the error that can sometimes also help

Comment: There is no error... it just takes longer... I'm just wondering if perhaps its a concurrency issue with Singlestore or some configuration beyond the scope of my software that is meaning it delays so long...?

Comment: Run an EXPLAIN SELECT.... and see what happens if all indexes are used, for perfoamnce analysis you need to show us the tables indexes and query.

Answer (score 0):

From a high level, cluster resources are much more utilized while the background software constantly writes to the table. The same resources that handle the constant writes are concurrently trying to serve the query, so it makes sense its faster when there is no writing.

A 'knob to turn' WRT database ingest performance is partition count - you can try creating a test DB w/ more partitions that the current DB (say 2x more). Then try querying from the test DB, both while the background software is running and while it is not - compare this to the DB w/ fewer partitions.

For general guidance on troubleshooting query performance, see this section of the docs: https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/query-data/query-procedures/troubleshooting-poorly-performing-queries.html

If you're an active customer, you can file a support ticket for the issue for some additional analysis of the backend workings

Answer (score 0):

From the information you mentioned, the most likely situation here would be a resource contention here caused by the said software and your database. One of the most likely root cause for this situation to happen would be caused by bad code and poorly-organized tables.

You might also want to look into other db solutions that can perform better than SingleStore with more effective use of resources. According to this article here from Altinity, StarRocks and ClickHouse can load data faster than SingleStore while using 4 to 10 times less resources.

Here’s the link to the said article: https://medium.com/altinity/loading-100b-rows-in-minutes-in-altinity-cloud-6bdb01c76d8e